# Convert hexadecimal character (ligature) to utf-8 character

Tags: python, pdf, character, ligature

I had a text content which is converted from a pdf file. There are some unwanted character in the text and I want to convert them to utf-8 characters.

For instance; 'Artificial Immune System' is converted like 'Arti*ﬁ*cial Immune System'. *ﬁ* is converted like a one character and I used `gdex` to learn the `ascii` value of the character but I don't know how to replace it with the real value in the all content.

Answer (score 18):

I guess what you're seeing are [*ligatures*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) — professional fonts have glyps that combine several individual characters into a single (better looking) glyph. So instead of writing "f" and "i", as two glyphs, the font has a single "fi" glyph. Compare "fi" (two letters) with "ﬁ" (single glyph).

In Python, you can use the [`unicodedata` module](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html) to manipute late Unicode text. You can also exploit the conversion to NFKD normal form to split ligatures:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(u'\uFB01')
'LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI'
>>> unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", u'Arti\uFB01cial Immune System')
u'Artificial Immune System'
```

So normalizing your strings with NFKD should help you along. If you find that this splits too much, then my best suggestion is to make a small mapping table of the ligatures you want to split and replace the ligatures manually:

```
>>> ligatures = {0xFB00: u'ff', 0xFB01: u'fi'}
>>> u'Arti\uFB01cial Immune System'.translate(ligatures)
u'Artificial Immune System'
```

Refer to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) to get a [list of ligatures in Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature#Ligatures_in_Unicode_.28Latin-derived_alphabets.29).